# FFMPEG- How to generate thumbnail from video in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, ffmpeg

I'm working on generating thumbnail from uploaded video in Codeigniter for this I'm using `ffmpeg` but when I'm trying to generate the thumbnail I'm getting this error

> ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libass.so.5:
>   undefined symbol: FT_Outline_EmboldenXY

I've already installed ffmpeg on my system, currently I'm trying to print the result.

This is my code to generate thumbnail

```
if ( $this->upload->do_upload( 'userFile' ) ) {

                        $videoData = $this->upload->data();
                        /*for thumbnail of video*/
                        echo "</pre>";
                        exec( "/tagittty/ffmpeg.exe" );
                        $videoFile = $_FILES['userFile']['name'];
                        exec( 'ffmpeg -i' . $videoFile . '  -r 1 -ss 00:00:50 -vf scale=1024:-1 -vframes 1 output.jpeg 2>&1', $result );
                        echo "<pre>";
                        print_r( $result );
                        echo "</pre>";
                        die();
                    }
```

Response I got after

```
ldd -r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libass.so.5
```

[image]

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: You should upgrade libfreetype on your system.

Comment: by using sudo apt-get upgrade libfreetype?

Comment: Are you on Debian/Ubuntu? Probably. I don't use those distros.

Comment: on Ubuntu. I'm unable to find package there

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=freetype6

Comment: libfreetyp6 is already updated.

Comment: What's the version?

Comment: (2.6.3-3ubuntu2.2)

Comment: What does `ldd -r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libass.so.5` show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162276/discussion-between-mr-pyramid-and-mulvya).

Comment: anyone here to fix this.?

Comment: Did you try the precompiled static binaries?

Comment: No, I ran the command in terminal and its working there but I don't know why its not working in php.

Comment: In php, check the path of the ffmpeg binary you're running and compare it with the version in terminal.

Comment: yeah did a cross check on it by `which ffmpeg` in terminal I have used the same path. :(

Comment: I was having the same issue with XAMPP. Turns out, even though my system's libfreetype is good and up-to-date, XAMPP has an outdated version bundled with it. I removed the link files for libreetype in /opt/lampp/lib and it defaulted to using the system's libfreetype instead.

If you're not using XAMPP, I'd imagine you're still facing the same problem, but I don't know where exactly you should look to find the bundled libraries to remove. Also, I'm not sure if removing them is even a good idea, so I guess take this answer with a grain of salt.